# Facebook SDK - publish post with external image

Tags: php, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am having hard time publishing external image to post. I am using PHP language and curl. I would like to post image (e.g. https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/17/58/sample-815141_1280.jpg) to facebook, but the only thing which get's posted is message without any image.

The problem with using *photo api* is that the post is posted as a picture and not as a post containing image. How can I accomplish this? I also tried with official PHP SDK but so far no luck.

```
$data['message'] = $_POST["content"];
$data['access_token'] = $page_access_token;

$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/feed';
if($_POST["picture"]!==""){
$data_post['url']=$_POST["picture"];
}


if($_POST["content"]!=="")
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
```